# No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoSizeTextType' in package not supported in 26.0.2

Tags: android

I have updated the support library versions to 26.0.2, `supportLibraryVersionAutoText = '26.0.2'`, and all of the related files is also updated now. Please see as follows

```
support = [
            design:                     "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersionAutoText}",
            recyclerView:               "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersionAutoText}",
            cardView:                   "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibraryVersionAutoText}",
            appCompat:                  "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersionAutoText}",
            appCompatV4:                "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersionAutoText}",
            annotation:                 "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibraryVersionAutoText}"
    ]
```

again the project build.gradle, I updated the

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}
allprojects{
    repositories{
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

But still when i add the variable in XML file it shows no resource identifier found . Please help what i am missing here .

Comment: Can you post your error ?

Comment: Error:(564) No resource identifier found for attribute 'autoSizeTextType' in package when i try to run the app

Comment: Can you post your textview code?

Comment: <TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                         
  android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
   app:text="@{model.mTextInvoice} app:text_color="@{model.mTextColorInvoice}"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"                          android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_default"
 android:text=""
 android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium"
  android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">   this is parent layout

Comment: when i add these lines Shows suspicious names should start with http :(

Comment: Use this : <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">;
<data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.zbooni.ui.model.activity.CartViewModel" />
    </data>

Comment: it shows error am i missing soemting there ?